# Div side by side without float

Tags: css, html, css-float

How can I make div 'left' and 'right' look like columns side by side?

I know I can use float:left on them and that will work... but on step 5 and 6 in here http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast...s/positioning/
the guy says it is possible, I can't get it work though...

Code:

```
<style>
div.left {
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}

div.right{
    background:green;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
}

.container{
    background:black;
    height:400px;
    width:450px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            LEFT
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            RIGHT
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see why you'd be having trouble getting `float` to work, if that is indeed your problem http://www.jsfiddle.net/zygnz/

Comment: maybe he is not clearing `clear:both` for instance? And his floats overlap / mix up.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The usual method when not using `float`s is to use `display: inline-block`: http://www.jsfiddle.net/zygnz/1/

```
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Do note its limitations though: There is a additional space after the first bloc - this is because the two blocks are now essentially `inline` elements, like `a` and `em`, so whitespace between the two counts. This could break your layout and/or not look nice, and I'd prefer not to strip out all whitespaces between characters for the sake of this working.

Floats are also more flexible, in most cases.

Comment: You can remove the space by setting the container's fontSize to zero.

Comment: Another way to remove space is by using `display:table-cell`.

Comment: There a blog article about those annoying spaces: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I have a large image in left DIV, so text in right DIV is shown at the bottom. Is there any way to get it back to the top?

Comment: @IvanKuckir, Any resolution to this? I'm having same issue. Will continue to research. Here's the same Fiddle above with extra content: http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/3050/

Answer (score 19):

A `div` is a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements), meaning that will behave as a block, and blocks can't stay side by side without being floated. You can however set them to [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements) with:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Give it a try...

---

Another way is to place them using:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
```

and/or

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```

**Note:** For this to work as expected, the wrapper element must have a `position:relative;` so that the elements with absolute positioning stay relative to their wrapper element.

Comment: Not a great solution, while it can work, you could easily end up with elements largely spaced elements due to it not actually being rendered next to the other div, and instead being rendered next to the left/right border of the parent container.

Comment: Note using `position: absolute; right: 0;` behaves exactly like a `float`.  Which means, if you have padding on your `div` it will overflow the container.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use CSS3 `flexbox` layout, which is [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) nowadays.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background:black;
    height:400px;
    width:450px;
}

.left {
    flex: 0 0 300px;
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
}

.right {
    flex: 0 1 100px;
    background:green;
    height:300px;
}
```

[See Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/3040/) (with legacy styles for maximum compatiblity) & [Learn more](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about flexbox.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on this, and i have already a number of solutions.
It is nice to have a high quality site, that i can use also for my convenience.
Because if you do not write these things down, you will eventually forget some parts.
And i can also recommend writing some basic's down if you are starting any kind of new programming/design.

So if the float functions are causing problems there is a couple of options you can try.

One is modify the div alignment in the div tag it self like so `<div class="kosher" align=left>`
If this does not suit you then there is another option with margin like so.

```
.leftdiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
.rightdiv {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 45%;
}
```

Don't forget to remove the `<div align=left>`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:table-cell;` for removing space between .Left and .Right

```css
div.left {
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}

div.right{
    background:green;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
}

.container{
    background:black;
    height:400px;
    width:450px;
}

.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="left">
      LEFT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="right">
      RIGHT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with margin for right div

```
margin: -200px 0 0 350px;
```

Comment: Works if the left div is of a known width/height