# Div goes under Div

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a layout with two divs on the same line. I need one div floated left and the other floated right so that the divs will stay on their respective sides no matter the browser size and the div on the right won't fall below the left floated div when the browser size is smaller than the two divs.

I need the browser to cut off the 2nd div after the 2 divs touch each other when the browser shrinks.

I had a picture to illustrate my question but I don't have enough reputation points to post it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619233/div-side-by-side-without-float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to float the divs? If not you can always create a wrapper for the divs with a minimum width set to allow the divs and a `position` of `relative` or `absolute` to stay next to each other,

```
#wrapper {
  min-width: 250px;
  position: relative
}
```

then set the inner divs display property to "inline-block".

```
.blocks {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

All together, this will create a "safety bubble" in which your divs can rest side by side without jumping to the next line, even after window resizing.


Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GD73j/1/).

**EDIT**

After a couple of trial and errors I believe we have an answer.
Javascript.
So in interest of time, I will post the code on jsFiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vulpCod3z/f4Pmz/). Breifly, what I added to the previous code was a script that ( on `window.onload`) you get the id's of both inner divs. You then create two objects to hold the position of their facing borders which are then compared to see if the second div ( one on the right ) has crossed into the first. The numbers in the div are there as a place marker to show that the div does not slide onto/under the other.
 *PS the 200px is just a demo number, they can be changed)

Comment: I don't want the divs to be right next to each other, I want one div on the left side of the screen and one on the right.

Comment: Ah spaces, I apologize. I left out some code. Just a `postion: absolute` in each div's css properties, and a `left: 0` and `right: 0` for the two inner divs.

Comment: This works pretty well but the two divs actually aren't small blocks. The div on the right overlaps the div on the left because they are so big and 200px isn't big enough, but I don't want the browser to stop shrinking after the two divs connect because they take up a lot of the browser. I want the div on the right to stop moving when it hits the other div and then the browser to be able to continue onward past it, covering it up.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to find the solution

Comment: Glad I could help. It's a great learning experience for me too :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you mean by "cut off" is that you want the left div to appear "in front of" the right div. To do this, you want to give the left div the css

```
{
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 z-index:2;
 display:inline-block;
 width:[number]px;
 height:[number]px;
}
```

and the right div

```
{
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 z-index:1;
 display:inline-block;
 width:[number]px;
 height:[number]px;
}
```

and to their shared parent div add the css "position:relative;".

Alternately, giving both divs "position:fixed;" might work, that makes them relative to the browser winder instead of the parent div, though that will give you very different outcomes when people try to scroll. You'll also need to give the left div a background that isn't transparent, or they'll just overlap. Also note that "position:absolute;" puts the divs 'outside the flow' as it were, in the sense that they will also overlap anything else you put in, and your design has to account for this.

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/RdX5P/

If by "the browser needs to cut off the second div" you mean you want the second div to just disappear when the window gets too small, just float the two divs and put them in a container div with set height and with "overflow:hidden;"

Comment: What I need is the second div to disappear like you mentioned near the end. Your solution sort of works but it still puts the second div under the first one, it just cuts off whatever reaches past the container div boundaries. I guess I could specify the height exactly so the div completely disappears but ideally, I would have the div not completely disappear at once, just having the div stop moving when it reaches the other div and the browser pass over it. I could use the position fixed method as the divs are part of a constant header but that wouldn't work in other cases.