# Align div to the right side

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the below HTML, Inside the Container I have Header, section and div.
With my current CSS below the div with class rightSideDiv does not show to right to the section element.

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  widht: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.headerTitle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 24px 24px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.sectionClass {
  width:249px;
  height:200px;
    background-color: yellow;

}

.rightSideDiv {
    width:249px;
  height:200px;
  border: 4px solid green;

}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="container"> 
    <header class="headerTitle"> Header Title  </header> 
    <section class="sectionClass"> .  </section>
    <div class="rightSideDiv"> </div>
  </div>
  </aside>
```

The section and div should be shown side by side. I dont want to modify the current HTML structure.  I have tried specifying float:left or right but both doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619233/div-side-by-side-without-float

Comment: Also spelling mistake in width - when corrected the width of the line will push the green box down

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716955/css-layout-aligning-two-divs-side-by-side

Answer (score 2):

Apply `float: left;` to both containers, use `width: 50%;` instead of px and `display: block;` header

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.headerTitle {
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 24px 24px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.sectionClass {
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;

}

.rightSideDiv {
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  background-color: pink;
  float: left;

}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="container"> 
    <header class="headerTitle"> Header Title  </header> 
    <section class="sectionClass"> .  </section>
    <div class="rightSideDiv"> </div>
  </div>
  </aside>
```

Comment: You still spell width wrong - when corrected the parent container will be too narrow

Comment: @mplungjan OP spelled width wrong. Thanks for pointing that out though. Fixed

Comment: I know he did. But your snippet editor pointed it out and your fix made it fail again :) You need 510px or so

Comment: Actually you need to have a sectionClass width of < 50%

Comment: @mplungjan I'm quite confident OP used border just to show the diff between divs. So I just edited answer to use bg color. Maybe that's better?

Comment: Works with 2x49% or no border :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox and `display:flex` instead. With very few changes to css you can get something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vnuz47va/2/

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 520px;
  background-color: red;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.headerTitle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 24px 24px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
  width:100%;
}

.sectionClass {
  width:249px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: yellow;

}

.rightSideDiv {
  width:249px;
  height:200px;
  border: 4px solid green;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="container"> 
    <header class="headerTitle"> Header Title  </header> 
    <section class="sectionClass"> .  </section>
    <div class="rightSideDiv"> </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Please don't make people go to another site to get their answer. Code should be on this site. See [answer].

Comment: You need to pay attention to the spelling mistake in witdh - and when fixed make it wider than 500 px

Answer (score 0):

change your css with this :

```
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}

.headerTitle {
    height: 24px;
    margin: 24px 24px 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.sectionClass {
    float : left;
    width: 50%;
    height:200px;
    background-color: yellow;

}

.rightSideDiv {
    float : right;
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    border: 4px solid green;

}
```

you can use float right and left to align your div, however your container has a width to 400 and your 2 div are 249+249 = 498 so there is a problem here..

Answer (score 0):

Change the H2 to `display: block;`, and then add `float:left`; to both boxes.

When you want divs side-by-side through floating, float them the same direction.

rightSideDiv is 8 pixels taller than the other. That is because the 4px border is added on top of the height. Consider using `box-sizing: border-box;`, which makes the border get absorbed into the set height, instead of being added on top of it.

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}

.headerTitle {
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 24px 24px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.sectionClass {
  width:249px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;

}

.rightSideDiv {
    width:249px;
  height:200px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="container"> 
    <header class="headerTitle"> Header Title  </header> 
    <section class="sectionClass"> .  </section>
    <div class="rightSideDiv"> </div>
  </div>
  </aside>
```