# Wrapped flex row items start at top

Tags: css, flexbox

Whilst trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868288/align-div-to-the-right-side#), I was trying to come up with a flex solution.  The closest I could get was this:

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;  /* puts spacing between left and right column */
}


.headerTitle {
  width:100%;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 24px 24px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.sectionClass {
  width: 249px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rightSideDiv {
  width: 249px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  box-sizing:border-box;     /* need this otherwise border  will take an extra 8px width in some browsers */

}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="headerTitle"> Header Title </header>
    <section class="sectionClass"> . </section>
    <div class="rightSideDiv"> </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

However, I couldn't make the 2 lower boxes start flush to the top heading.  Is there a way of doing this using flex?  I tried `align-items` and `align-self` but that didn't seem to do anything.

I also tried adding a pseudo element to the container with `flex-grow:1;` but it didn't grow in the required manner.

It would be interesting to see if flex can handle this as I'm still trying to learn the intricacies of it

Comment: Related (possibly a canonical dupe target, but I haven't spent a lot of time with flexbox questions on SO) https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611670/2756409

Comment: If by any chance you *haven't* seen Michael_B around [tag:css], and you still need help with flexbox, definitely spend some time checking out [his answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:3597276+[flexbox]) on the subject. He covers CSS Grid Layout pretty well, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `align-content: flex-start` to the `.container` div:

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:space-between; /* puts spacing between left and right column */
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.headerTitle {
  width:100%;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 24px 24px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.sectionClass {
  width: 249px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rightSideDiv {
  width: 249px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* need this otherwise border will take an extra 8px width in some browsers */
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="headerTitle"> Header Title </header>
    <section class="sectionClass"> . </section>
    <div class="rightSideDiv"> </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: ah nice, knew it would be something simple.  What's the difference between align items and align content?

Comment: @Pete [What's the difference between align-content and align-items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539262/whats-the-difference-between-align-content-and-align-items)

Comment: Perfect, thanks @TylerH